# PHPUnit Mock 'method' method returns NULL

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am aware the title makes this seem very similar to a frequently asked question. This is not the same issue.

In my Laravel test suite, I'm trying to mock the `Illuminate\Http\Request` object to make `getClientIp` return a specific value:

```
$this->mockedRequest = $this->createMock(Request::class);
$this->mockedRequest->method('getClientIp')->willReturn('geralt.of.rivia');
```

However, the above line of code gives me the following error:

```
Call to a member function willReturn() on null
```

In other words, the PHPUnit mock `method()` method is itself, returning null, making it obviously impossible to chain `->willReturn()` after it.

I have no idea what could be causing this issue, and Googling the error is exceptionally difficult due to the number of people asking why their mocked method is returning `null` (because they didn't chain `->willReturn()`.

Any insight?

- PHP 7.0
- Laravel 5.3
- PHPUnit 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, I finally find the answer immediately after posting the StackOverflow question.

As it happens, the `Request` object in Laravel contains a method called `method()`. This is a known issue with PHPUnit. If the class you are mocking implements a method called `method()`, you can get around this by chaining an `expects()` first:

```
$this->mockedRequest-->expects($this->any())->method('getClientIp')->willReturn('geralt.of.rivia');
```